How do I find and move a string of consonants in Python?
I am new to Python and need to make a Pig Latin translator, that reads a .txt file, and outputs a new piglatin .txt file for a project. But I cannot figure out how to move the consonant clusters to the end of the word. How would I make it so that I can move the consonant clusters to the right position?
def main():
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
  # pigFile = open('C:\\Users\\grink\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\project\\origin.txt', 'r')
  pigFile = open('origin.txt', 'r')
  pigOut = open('piglatin.txt', 'w')
  for line in  pigFile.readlines():
    pigList = line.split()
    t = translate(pigList, vowels)
    print("Input: ", pigList)
    print("Converted: ", t)
    # w = write(t, pigOut)'
    writeplatin(t, pigOut)
  pigFile.close()

def translate(pigList, vowels):
  newPigList = []

  for word in pigList:
    if word[0] in vowels: # if the word starts with vowel
      newPigList.append(word + "way ") #add to new list
    else: #if not vowel
      newPigList.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay") 

  return newPigList

def writeplatin(pigList, pigOut):
  # pigOut.write("\n".join(pigList))
  for word in pigList:
    pigOut.write(word + '\n')
main()

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I've been Googling for days and haven't found a solution.
EDIT: I found a solution, thanks for the responses and help
def main():
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
  # pigFile = open('C:\\Users\\grink\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\project\\origin.txt', 'r')
  pigFile = open('origin.txt', 'r')
  pigOut = open('piglatin.txt', 'w')
  for line in  pigFile.readlines():
    pigList = line.split()
    t = translate(pigList, vowels)
    print("Input: ", pigList)
    print("Converted: ", t)
    # w = write(t, pigOut)'
    writeplatin(t, pigOut)
  pigFile.close()

def translate(pigList, vowels):
  newPigList = []

  for word in pigList:
    if word[0] in vowels: # if the word starts with vowel
      newPigList.append(word + "way ") #add to new list
    else:
     for pos in range(1, len(word)):
            if word[pos] in vowels:
                pos += 1 if word[pos] == 'u' and word[pos - 1] == "q" else 0
                newPigList.append(word[pos:] + word[:pos] + "ay")
                break 

  return newPigList

def writeplatin(pigList, pigOut):
  # pigOut.write("\n".join(pigList))
  for word in pigList:
    pigOut.write(word + '\n')
main()


can you provide a minimal reproducible example with your expected output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You're not closing pigOut btw - maybe use a with block?

You can use a regular expression to match all the consonants at the beginning of the word. ^[b-df-hj-np-tv-wz]*. Extract this and move it to the end.

The search [python] "pig latin" answers:1 will find many previous answers showing how to implement Pig Latin translators.

Using the comment suggestions, I found a solution:
def main():
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
  # pigFile = open('C:\\Users\\grink\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\project\\origin.txt', 'r')
  pigFile = open('origin.txt', 'r')
  pigOut = open('piglatin.txt', 'w')
  for line in  pigFile.readlines():
    pigList = line.split()
    t = translate(pigList, vowels)
    print("Input: ", pigList)
    print("Converted: ", t)
    # w = write(t, pigOut)'
    writeplatin(t, pigOut)
  pigFile.close()

def translate(pigList, vowels):
  newPigList = []

  for word in pigList:
    if word[0] in vowels: # if the word starts with vowel
      newPigList.append(word + "way ") #add to new list
    else:
     for pos in range(1, len(word)):
            if word[pos] in vowels:
                pos += 1 if word[pos] == 'u' and word[pos - 1] == "q" else 0
                newPigList.append(word[pos:] + word[:pos] + "ay")
                break 

  return newPigList

def writeplatin(pigList, pigOut):
  # pigOut.write("\n".join(pigList))
  for word in pigList:
    pigOut.write(word + '\n')
main()

